# Read xml data from url using php

Tags: php, xml

I want to read data and xml attributes values from this url using php-

[journey planner](http://journeyplanner.tfl.gov.uk/user/XML_TRIP_REQUEST2?language=en&sessionID=0&place%20_origin=London&type_origin=stop&name_origin=Alexa%20nder%20Road&place_destinat%20ion=London&type_destination=stop&name_destination=Prince%20Of%20Wales%20%20Gate&itdDate=20110801&itdTime=0800)

I have never worked with xml before..So i need some suggestion for doing my task..

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like [searched the PHP manual for "XML"](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php)?

Comment: I suggest this link for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405424/read-xml-from-a-url-in-php-with-curl.

Comment: One more suggestion for you http://lt.php.net/simplexml_load_file

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `simplexml_load_file(string $filename)` to this end. Just pass into this function the full URL such as:

```
$url="your url";

$xmlinfo = simplexml_load_file($url);

print_r($xmlinfo);
```