# Reading XML POST data from URL

Tags: php, xml

I am working with a 3rd party SMS supplier which they are sending me the delivery report of the SMS via URL as below:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/dlr.php <DeliveryReport><message id="024042313063119191" sentdate="2014/04/23 15:06:31" donedate="2014/04/23 15:06:35" status="DELIVERED" gsmerror="0" price="7.0" /></DeliveryReport>
```

And i am trying to read the XML data in dlr.php like below:

```
<?php

// read raw POST data

$postData = file_get_contents("php://input");

 $dom = new DOMDocument();

 $dom->loadXML($postData);

 // create new XPath object for quering XML elements (nodes)

$xPath = new domxpath($dom);

// query “message” element

 $reports = $xPath->query("/DeliveryReport/message");

 // write out attributes of each “message” element

foreach ($reports as $node) {

  echo “<br>id: “ . $node->getAttribute('id');

  echo “<br>sent: “ . $node->getAttribute('sentdate');

  echo “<br>done: “ . $node->getAttribute('donedate');

  echo “<br>status: “ . $node->getAttribute('status');

  echo “<br>gsmerrorcode: “ . $node->getAttribute('gsmerrorcode');

}

?>
```

I am getting this error:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in dlr.php
```

Any help how can I read the posted data correctly.

Thanks,

Comment: do you call to sms gateway? OR sms gateway sending data to your dlr.php?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499581/read-xml-data-from-url-using-php?rq=1

Comment: @Samiul, the sms gateway sending me the delivery report. I provided them my url: http://www.mydomain.com/dlr.php

Comment: @kjames. I tried it did not work

Comment: can you run var_dump($_POST) and let me know what's the output?

Comment: @Tommy which SMS gateway API you are using?

Comment: @SamiulAminShanto.. I got array(0){}

Comment: I have tried your code in my local env, and work fine. what did you get output for variable $postData? empty? If your get $postData empty then your sms gateway not sending data or can not reach to your dlr.php

Comment: @SamiulAminShanto. Yes empty

Comment: Maybe the hosting provider block the post? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this function for getting data from XML

```
function getFeed($feed_url) 
{

        $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
        $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
        foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) : ?>
        <?php
        $pdate = $entry->pubDate;
            $pdate = rtrim($pdate,' -500');
            $pdate = explode(', ',$pdate);
        ?>
        <div >
              <a href="<?php echo $entry->link; ?>" target="_blank">
            <span > <?php echo $entry->title;?></span></a> <?php echo $pdate[1]; ?>
        </div>
        <?php 
        endforeach; 
    }

    getFeed("// Your URL");
```